# What would be the regex for matching an alphanumeric string with 4 digits & 1 alphabet?

Tags: javascript, java, php, regex

For example, it should allow strings like '1234n' , '1234a' . Max string size is 5 and it should only allow a sequence of 4 digits followed by a character.

Comment: `\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: `\d{4}[a-zA-Z]` try this

Comment: 1. What have you tried? . 2. Which language are you using?

Comment: /^\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/

Comment: First Read some basics of regex you will get to know  : https://dzone.com/refcardz/regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
^\d{4}[A-Za-z]$
```

- `^\d{4}` matches 4 digits at the start
- `[A-Za-z]$` matches any single alphabetic character at the end

Comment: don't think you need the `^` or the `$`

Answer (score -1):

```
^\d{4}\w$
```

test and modify here
https://regex101.com/r/aQ3wJ0/1

Comment: Max string size is 5